# Linq - NHibernate. How to combine LINQ conditions in group with OR operator. IQuerable.Concat alternative

Tags: c#, sql, linq, nhibernate

I have `IQuerable<MyEntity>` and filters(conditions list), that i want to apply to my query.

Schematically I want to get looks like

```
                               //First filter group              // Second filter group
QUERY = from MYTABLE where ( Name = "User" and Age = 19  ) OR ( Name = "Alex", and Age > 20 )

query = (query.Where(x => x.Name == value)
              .Where(x => x.Age  == value)
              .Where(x => x.Post == value)) 
        OR (
        (query.Where(x => x.Name == value)
              .Where(x => x.RegistrationDate == value))
```

**I need to create `IQuerable`, that will contain result first and second filter group(`IQuerable`).**

But, I can't execute at first 1-st filter group, then 2-nd group and concat results, because after appling my filters I must to do a few operations with `IQuarable`.

I tried create queryes and `query.Concat()` with main, but `NHibernate` does not support this method

```
    public static IQueryable<IDevice> ApplyGroups(this IQueryable<IDevice> query, IList<ITerminalGroup> groups)
    {
        foreach (ITerminalGroup group in groups)
        {
            IQueryable<IDevice> groupQuery = query.AsQueryable();
            // apply to groupQuery conditions
            groupQuery = groupQuery.ApplyGroup(group);

            query = query.Concat(groupQuery);
        }
        return query;
    }

    static IQueryable<IDevice> ApplyGroup(this IQueryable<IDevice> query, ITerminalGroup group)
    {
        foreach (ITermGroupCondition condition in group.Conditions)
        {
             query = query.Where(x => x.SpecialAttributes.Any(sa => x.Id == condition.AttribId && sa.AttribValue.Equals(condition.Value)));
        }
        return query;
    }
```

Count of conditions may be different, I do not know it in advance

How to combine LINQ conditions in group with OR operator ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [PredicateBuilder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) to do that; combine the conditions with the `PredicateBuilder.Or` method, and pass the resulting condition to the Where method.